# Why is ios::app (append) not working in C++?

Tags: c++, gcc, file-io, file-handling

I am using GNU C++ with Code::Blocks.
In the following code I am using ios::app to append data at the end of the file "employee.txt" . The code is working fine in Turbo C++ but GNU C++ seems to be causing a bit trouble. No data is getting stored in the file. What could be the possible reason and solution?

Edit- After Trying the solutions given here, it worked but now it is giving the same problem again. Even After entering the data, the file is still empty. I have updated the code.

```
        if(ch==1)
    {
        cout<<"Enter Data for employee\n";
        e.getdata();
        f.open("employee.txt", ios::app|ios::binary);
        f.write((char*)&e, sizeof(employee));
        f.close();

    }
    if(ch==2)
    {
        int en;
        int flag=0;
        cout<<"Enter Employee No. to search\n";
        cin>>en;
        f.open("employee.txt", ios::in | ios::binary );
        f.read((char*)&e, sizeof(e));
        while(f)
        {
            if(e.reteno()==en)
            {
                flag=1;
                e.putdata();
            }
            f.read((char*)&e, sizeof(e));
        }
        if(flag==0)
        {
            cout<<"Record Not Found\n";
        }
        f.close();
    }
```

Comment: you should always check if a function succeeds or not i.e. `if (f.is_open()) ...`

Comment: According to your code, you use `ios::out` when trying to append, and `ios::app` when trying to search for an employee. Are you sure you got that right? Also, your code example is not minimal. Can you isolate the part that is causing problems (perhaps a new main function with just a few lines for opening and trying to append something)?

Comment: edited my code a bit, please look into it again.

Comment: It's way too much code still. Please provide a minimal example.

Comment: Made the code smaller. And I think the answers solved that problem.

Comment: If you provide just *what* the trouble is (sample session, compiler error, whatever) you have better chances of getting help. (Although people were apparently able to spot the error here quickly.)

Comment: "Seems to be causing a bit trouble" = ???

Comment: I have edited the question. Hope this time the problem is much clearer.

Comment: It's not, unfortunately. Please study the guidelines, don't just skip over them. For example, a potential reader can't take your code and compile it without lots of adjustments which may or may not reflect the way you use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the branch `ch==1` you should specify `ios::app` in order to add records. i.e. `ios::app|ios::out|ios::binary`

When reading, `ios::app` should not be specified since you want to read from the beginning. Instead use `ios::in|ios::binary`

That said, you may want to instead of using read/write use `<<` and `>>` to read and write to the file.

e.g.

```
ofstream& operator<<(ofstream& f, const employee& e)
{
    f << e.eno << ',' << e.name << ',' << e.balance;
    return f;
}

...

f << e;
```

Comment: yeah i completely got that mistake. Just one thing, what should i use in the  other branch?

Comment: i have edited my code once more. the file created is still empty after adding the data. the append does not seem to work.

Comment: in ch==1 you should have `f.open("employee.txt", ios::app|ios::binary);` and in ch==2 you should have `f.open("employee.txt", ios::in|ios::binary)` app sets the file pointer to the end of the file so opening a file for read with app makes little sense

Comment: It worked once. Next time it did not. I have updated the code in the question.

Comment: Maybe the question has been edited since you answered, but there is no C I/O in the example given.   There is binary I/O, but C++ streams do support that (assuming they are opened appropriately).   Generally, binary I/O and use of stream insertion operators are used for different things.

Comment: @Peter you are right, i misread read with fread. early in the morning here and B.C. .. before coffee

Answer (score 0):

Opening a file to be read in `ios::app` mode doesn't make sense, because `ios::app` moves your file pointer to the end of the file, so that whatever you add gets appended to it.

In `ch == 1` use `f.open ("employee.txt",  ios::app | ios::binary);`. This will open the file for you to append to it.

In `ch == 2` use `f.open("employee.txt",  ios::in | ios::binary)`. This will open the file for you to read from it.

Comment: It worked once. Next time it did not. I have updated the code in the question.